# Win32Exception occurs when ShowDialog for a WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013

My Excel AddIn iswritten in C#, .NET 4.5.1. After install the addin, there is a ribbon tab (w/ ribbon buttons) showing up in Excel. When I click one ribbon button, a WPF window will pop up. 
It works fine for a while. However, after I click ribbon buttons several times and click one button again, nothing shows up. I checked my log file and see Win32Exception. I am not sure what causes this and how to fix this.   BTW, My addin used to work fine on my PC, recently I upgraded to VS2013 & .NET4.5.1. In the past I used VS2010 + .NET 4.0. I am not sure if it has anything to do with this upgrade.

Thanks!

```
                XLFunctionModel = new MainViewModel(XLApp, UnityContainer);
                xlfuncWindow = new XLFuncWindow();

//http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/01/16/iwin32window-owner-for-wpf-window.aspx
                var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(xlfuncWindow);
                helper.Owner = wndHandle.Handle;

                xlfuncWindow.DataContext = XLFunctionModel;
                bool? successNullable = xlfuncWindow.ShowDialog();


Name:Win32Exception
Message:Invalid window handle
Target:Void .ctor(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, System.String, IntPtr, MS.Win32.HwndWrapperHook[])
Stack:   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Initialize(HwndSourceParameters parameters)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource..ctor(HwndSourceParameters parameters)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Do you ever do anything with that xlfuncWindow?  If you don't then you'll just leak the window handle.  Do that enough and Windows refuses to create another, kaboom.  Do use the code that's in the web post you linked to.

Comment: I close it in other place. What else do I need to do to get rid of the exception? Thanks